# What is the advantage of CountDownlatch over wait/notify mechanism?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have read this answer:

[Difference between wait-notify and CountDownLatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10594014/difference-between-wait-notify-and-countdownlatch)

I know both process are different,

1. CountDownlatch is a new mechanism while wait/notify is a pristine
   way of co coordinating between threads
2. wait is a method of Object, await is a method of CountDownlatch.
3. using CountDownlatch is easier and cleaner etc etc.

My question is more of the functional aspect:

Is there any situation which cannot be solved by wait/notify mechanism but can be solved only by CountDownLatch?

If no,then functionally, CountDownlatch was introduced solely to make coordination between threads easier and cleaner, right?

Comment: You say "pristine", but what you really mean is that wait/notify is a _lower-level of abstraction_ than CountdownLatch.  If you wanted to create your own version of CountdownLatch, it would make sense to use wait and notify in your implmentation, but it would make no sense to use a CountdownLatch in implementing your own version of wait/notify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can create the same functionality just with wait, notify, synchronized and so on. CountDownLatch is a normal Java class implemented using such primitives. For details you can have a look at the actual source code: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.java

Answer (score 1):

The classes in `java.util.concurrent` are designed to make certain multithreading scenarios more easier to code and manage. You can use low-level constructs such as `wait` and `notify` but you really need to know what you are doing.

Here is the excerpt from the API:

> Utility classes commonly useful in concurrent programming. This
>   package includes a few small standardized extensible frameworks, as
>   well as some classes that provide useful functionality and are
>   otherwise tedious or difficult to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a case where you may not want to wait if a condition is met. You could get your hands dirty and probe a lock, but this is often buggy.

A CountDownLatch comes to the rescue, yes for convenience, but not solely to solve the wait/notify paradigm.

The obvious use of CountDownLatch as a way to wait for multiple conditions also comes to mind.

Why reinvent the wheel when it's available first party?